# What does "money is like mush not not" mean?

Tags: meaning, slang

I'm not sure if it's off topic or not, so apologies if it's irrelevant.
Can anyone explain the meaning of a specific slang phrase, "money is like mush not not"?
I keep seeing it in random places but couldn't find an explanation for it in almighty Google.

Comment: If you're not sure if it's off topic, why not take [the site tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour) first?  You could also look at the [Help Center](https://english.stackexchange.com/help) for a lot more info.  As it is, your question is unanswerable (and thus off topic) without more context.

Comment: @Anon Can you link to some examples, quoting a sentence or a paragraph each time, and citing the sources?

Comment: not not is a double negative, so it means 'money is like mush'. or you can think of 'not not' as a double-sided question 'not. (definite), not? (question)', and so it is a figurative speech statement

Comment: @RogerSinasohn: "As it is, your question is unanswerable (and thus off topic) without more context." I disagree. The OP has no way to know whether someone can come up with a great answer before asking the question. The question itself is crystal clear ("What does XYZ mean"). It concerns a english slang term (which I never heard or read - I can only assume that some people actually did use it, or the OP would not have stumbled across it). A non-english speaker might not know enough about the language to do a research like StoneyB did in their answer.

Comment: @AnoE -- From the [How To Ask](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) page: _...if you give us details and context, we can provide a useful answer._  Without adequate context, there's not a lot one can do.  StoneyB managed to go above and beyond here, but that is not required.  And if it is a basic question from an [English Language Learner](https://ell.stackexchange.com/), then perhaps they ought to visit that site instead.  (I'm not of the whole _you must have a doctorate in English to be here_ mindset, but posters do need some level of competence and to make some effort.)

Comment: @RogerSinasohn, from https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic,  "Word choice and usage" and maybe "Dialect differences" would be fitting. It mentions off-topic "The meaning of words, or synonyms for words, unless you have first looked them up in a dictionary or thesaurus.", but the OP did check "almighty Google" and nothing came up (I didn't check myself, but I'd assume this sentence does not come up in the OALD either :) ).

Comment: @AnoE -- Well, I'm somewhat new to ELU, so I'll defer to the far more experienced Lawrence who suggested that the OP edit the question to ***link to some examples, quoting a sentence or a paragraph each time, and citing the sources***.  I will note that _unanswerable_ was demonstrably a bit of hyperbole, given that StoneyB was able to provide one.  I don't know if his google-fu is just that much stronger than the OP's or if he has inside (local?) knowledge.  But he deserves a lot of credit for his answer.  (Which is likely why he has 58k rep.)

Answer (score 59, accepted):

This is not standard Anglo English, even of a slang variety. I find it only in posts from SE Asia (Singapore, Thailand, Hong Kong) where it appears to be the sort of catchphrase that merchandisers put on t-shirts and knick-knacks. Its full form is

> Money is like mush not not good kcept it espread.

A witty blog called [*Talk Shirty to Me*](http://talkshirtytome.blogspot.com/2015/05/money-islke-mush-not-not-good-kcept-it.html) posts a photograph of a storefront with a dress bearing this phrase and explains the phrase as a quote from Francis Bacon, translated into the local (?Malaysian?) version of English:<sup>†</sup>

> Money is like muck — not good except it be spread. —‘Of Seditions and Troubles’

Bacon is speaking of the manure of farm animals, which was in his day regarded as the most effective fertilizer for crops; in his *Apothegmes* he attributed the thought to his friend, Jeremy Bettenham, Reader at Gray's Inn:

> Mr. Bettenham vsed to say; *That Riches were like Mucke: When it lay, vpon an heape, it gaue but a stench, and ill odour; but when it was spread vpon the ground, then it was cause of much fruit.*

---

<sup>†</sup> <sub>There is considerable cogency to user hobbs’ comment that *I don't think it was “translated” so much as ”incompetently transcribed“, likely by someone who doesn't read or write any variety of English*; and this is supported by user elmer007’s observation that *is like* is realized as “islke” on this dress. On the other hand, the *Talk Shirty to Me* blogger observes that *not not* may be an intensive reduplication characteristic of some languages. Whatever the process, we seem to be dealing with a ‘magical’ use of English rather than a conventional utterance like the Bacon/Bettenham originals.</sub>

Comment: A line in the Musical Comedy, "Hello Dolly" modernizes Bacon's proverb(if he indeed conceived it). 
*Dolly Levi: Money, pardon the expression, is like manure. It's not worth a thing unless it's spread around, encouraging young things to grow.*

Comment: @Tom He did not conceive it. In *Apothegmes* he attributed it to his friend, Jeremy Bettenham, Reader at Gray's Inn: "Mr. Bettenham vsed to say; *That Riches were like Mucke: When it lay, vpon an heape, it gaue but a stench, and ill odour; but when it was spread vpon the ground, then it was cause of much fruit.*"

Comment: I don't think it was "translated" so much as "incompetently transcribed", likely by someone who doesn't read or write any variety of English. Mistakes like losing place, doubling words, moving spaces, and substituting similar words or letters follow naturally when the person doing the copying doesn't have any sense of the meaning. "kcept" and "espread" don't show any evidence of being words in any dialect.

Comment: I suspect that if this one hasn't yet made it to [Engrish.com](http://engrish.com), it will soon...

Comment: "islke" islke the referenced photograph

Comment: @hobbs and elmer007, see my footnote.

Comment: @hobbs: You're right. "mush" is probably the original word, but "kcept" is probably a misreading of "except" where the "e" was handwritten so badly it looked like an "⍳", and "espread" could have resulted from missing a "b" and a space from "be spread". I've seen a shirt with "Be your owie kind of beautiful" where the font makes the "e" look like an "⍳" and at a glance the "owie" actually does look like "own"... In general a lot of goods from China have serious spelling problems.